# How to add a new app.xaml to WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wrote an application for Server-client connection.
In WPF project, there is an App.xaml that have start up method.
I want to do the same with an App2.xaml by copy and change the name + Startup URI for client UI
The code in App2.xaml like this

```
<Application x:Class="assembly_line_balance_demo_ga_dp_tttn09_2013.App2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" StartupUri="View/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But after I rebuild my project, it does not show new start up object in Properties solution.
Because Client & Server share the code inside, so I need to config both UI in one project and build to 2 different apps.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is allowed just One App.xaml per Project.

You can change the Start-Up Uri
like this:

On the file App.xaml
Remove the StartupUri attribute:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication4.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <!-- StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" -->
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

on the file App.xaml.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        // Add this override function
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Args.Contains("Client"))
                this.StartupUri = new Uri("View/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            else
                this.StartupUri = new Uri("View/MainWindowServer.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
    }
```

Then you can call

```
YourApplication.exe Client
```

or

```
YourApplication.exe Server
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But this way isn't flexible enough, but definitely it work.

Comment: You can create two projects and add the shared main class as link reference on second project. Or you could receive some parameter by command line to Specify the Startup window.

Comment: With above code you can call on DOS: YourApplication.exe Client